# Android 'AT' command workflow. Difference between Linux 'at' and Android 'AT' command

Tags: android, linux, kernel, modem, uart

Android 'AT' command forces the modem to set specified settings and execute test cases. Does the 'AT' command only applicable for modem?

Can someone describe how 'AT' command is handled in UART? I'm expecting the steps of command execution to understand the workflow of 'AT' command.

Linux 'at' command is to queue, examine or delete jobs for later execution. Can 'AT command in android do the same?

Comment: The details of the modem are not normally accessable on production android builds, but rather reserved to system components.  Ordinary applications are only allowrd to use derived functionality such as network, calls, sms, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thank you for the response. I know that AT parser is vendor specific. I'm just looking for a general overview of AT command workflow.

Comment: *"how 'AT' command is handled in UART?"* -- It would be handled as ordinary data just like any other data that is transmitted or received.

Comment: Modem "AT" commands have **absolutely nothing** to do with the unix command-line "at" tool.